# How to parse S3 object expiry date using NodeJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, parsing, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the expiry date and time of an AWS S3 object. I'm using Node.JS/JavaScript.

I can get the object data using the AWS SDK and `s3.headObject(params)` command and from the response I can get the Expiration string:

`expiry-date="Wed, 20 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="ExpireCachedAssets"`

How can I parse the string to get a JavaScript date object and check how long until it expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output always comes in that way, you can use regex to retrieve the date:

```
"([^"]+)GMT"'
```

that would match everything from `"` to the `GTM"`, which retrieves date it as:

```
new Date('expiry-date="Wed, 20 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="ExpireCachedAssets"'.match('"([^"]+)GMT"')[0]);
// Wed Jan 20 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

P.S. You might want to use `getTime()` to get a UNIX timestamp.

P.S. S. Consider using fallback in case there is no match found.